# How to collapse Android notifications?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I'm sending a C2DM update to my Android app every 1/2 hour, which creates a Notification. Problem is, when I wake up in the morning I get 15 Notifications queued up in the status bar.

How do I only keep the latest notification, overwriting previous ones?

I tried looking at the C2DM documentation (http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) which mentions a parameter called collapse_key, but I couldn't find an explanation for how to use it, nor am I sure the solution lies on the C2DM side.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is answered, but I'll add one point of clarification. Collapse key isn't meant for situations like this - from the docs: "[collapse key] - An arbitrary string that is used to collapse a group of like messages when the device is offline, so that only the last message gets sent to the client. This is intended to avoid sending too many messages to the phone when it comes back online." Once the intent is run on the phone (your code is being called), the C2DM message has been sent, delivered, and forgotten, as far as C2DM code is concerned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to cancel any previous notifications that has been set on the view you can try setting one of these flags.

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT or  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
```

Something like this should replace your old notification i believe

```
 NotificationManager mManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,test.class);
 Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Notify", System.currentTimeMillis());
 notification.setLatestEventInfo(this,"App Name","Description of the notification",
 PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getBaseContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
 mManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Answer (score 3):

`Notification` has a property called `number` that shows a little number below the icon (for multiple notification). It lets you use the same Icon for Multiple Notification.

Use the same `ID` while updating your notification. :) Cheers.

Comment: Accepting Rahul's answer because it answered to my original question, but I definitely used the number property as well-- thanks for the tip!

Comment: @yayitswei, that's fine, i framed my answer as an addition to Rahul's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, there is a parameter in your C2DM request that is called `delay_while_idle`.  Make sure you are NOT including that or make it false.  Your phone is "idle" when the screen is off (ie while you are sleeping).  Google queues up all your messages on the server until the phone is not idle (ie when you turn on the screen in the morning).  Then, Google sends all 15 messages at once and you display them at that time.

In the chrome to phone source, there is a method called `sendNoRetry` with this line:

```
if (delayWhileIdle) {
            postDataBuilder.append("&")
                .append(PARAM_DELAY_WHILE_IDLE).append("=1");
}
```

Make sure it is not true, then Google servers will send you your C2DM message every 30 minutes as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**collapse_id** key should do the job. For updating any previous notification, just use the same key. To generate a new notification on device, use a different key.

For example,
* for chat notifications use the key "chat" (collapse_id = "chat")
* for invitations use the key "invite" (collapse_id = "invite")

So all the unqiue collapse_id notifications will group on device.

For more details visit: https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification