# android: cancel notification on back pressed

Tags: android, notifications, back

I want to cancel all notifications related to my app when the back button is clicked. I am not able to find a way. Have you any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it help

```
@Override
```

public void onBackPressed() {

```
// write code for canceling the notification
return;
```

}

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to cancel all notifications

Comment: Ok what kind of notification you want cancel?

Comment: I am downloading a file from a server using an asynctask and I am updating my notification bar in the "onProgressUpdate". I want to stop download and cancel notification on back pressed.

Comment: Ok means you want to stop operation which is done in async task, right? In that case in async task write below method instead of writing in onProgressUpdate @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
   mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading wait.....");
   mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
   mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
   mProgressDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
   mProgressDialog.show();
  }

Comment: Check these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740103/how-to-collapse-android-notifications   https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Notifications/Notify1/src/com/commonsware/android/notify/NotifyDemo.java

Answer (score 0):

this may Helps you

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {    
    stopSelf();
    return;
    }
```