# Website inducing alert on mobile phone

Tags: php, android, iphone

I am building a php webpage to be browsed on computers, which is having some email sending and calendar functions.

I would like to try, when sending email messages or creating calendar events from computer browsers, will it be possible to trigger alerts, such as sounds and vibrations in iPhone and Androld systems?

If not, then I may have to do some apps. Thanks!

Comment: Look at C2DM for android, and APN for iPhone. Both are push notification services.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this for android phones:

```
function sendMessageToPhone($authCode, $deviceRegistrationId, $msgType, $messageText, $infoType, $messageInfo) {

$headers = array('Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' . $authCode);
$data = array(
    'registration_id' => $deviceRegistrationId,
    'collapse_key' => $msgType,
    'data.message' => $messageText,
    'data.type'    => $infoType,
    'data.data'    => $messageInfo
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");
if ($headers)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

return $response;
```

}

Comment: just call the function after the mail is sent..may be after mail() function. Note that you need to supply a proper device registration id  before calling the function.

Comment: thanks! is 'registration_id' being the recipient's id or my id? and how can I know the correct syntax for 'collapse_key', 'data.type' and 'data.data'? Thanks again!

Comment: registration id is for recepient device id. regarding other, i suggest you to read the android developer guide. also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740103/how-to-collapse-android-notifications

Comment: I see! how can I know someone's "registration IDs"? Shall I ask the one who is going to receive my message to look into his android phone? and how can he check it? Thanks alot!!

Comment: yes you have to ask. its a id used for identifying a specific user on android services...moreover i would suggest to go with the advice of @James.Elsey.  Look at C2DM for android, and APN for iPhone. Both are push notification services.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16913/discussion-between-ham-and-mrinal-purohit)